# How to use instance object with request.FILES and request.POST

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

**views.py**

```
   form=Create_Award_list_form(request.POST or None,instance=obj,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

> using request.FILES django doesn't let me to use instance object and
>   using instance django doesn't let to use request.FILES.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a **python** error, a **keyword argument** is just a **positional argument** with a **default** value ,you must place all keyword arguments after positional arguments.
in simple way,place your arguments with a default value in last.

```
form=Create_Award_list_form(request.POST or None,request.FILES,instance=obj)
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do *not* use `request.POST or None`. The `or None` part is an anti-pattern, since a POST request can be perfectly valid, but still empty.

You initialize a form with GET or POST data by passing `request.GET` or `request.POST` to the `data` parameter (this is the first one if you did not override `__init__` with another first one), and the `request.FILES` to the `files` parameter (which is the second one).

You thus can construct such form with:

```
form=Create_Award_list_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not Django complaining, that's a Python syntax error.

The (more) correct syntax is

```py
form = Create_Award_list_form(
    data=(request.POST or None),
    files=(request.FILES or None),
    instance=obj,
)
```

but really, just use a `FormView` or `UpdateView` even and save yourself some pain and time.